# how do I create "reopen" app button for iOS apps in background mode? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-background-mode

My app plays audio in background mode.

Question: when a user exits the app, how do you add a button/link to the top left screen to return them to the app?

(example pictured is google maps)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: iOS put that button there because Google Maps is using location in the background. You can't add arbitrary buttons to the screen outside your app.

Answer (score 0):

By default, media apps are not meant to do this.

You could pretend to be a Navigation app and ask for Location Services permissions to get access to Core Location. See Apple's documentation on it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

Although I doubt that would get approved on the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've also seen this option appear in Microsoft Teams when in a voice/phone conversation, so maybe it's not necessarily restricted to Location based apps.

Comment: So does Webex Teams. They both have VoIP capabilities which grant them a status bar icon when they're in the background, you could pretend to be a VoIP capable app instead, although that comes with its own limitations. It really isn't a technical issue, I'm mostly worried about Apple rejecting it for going against their Human Interface Guidelines.